# Is there a fast way to match an excel doc to a function in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I know that question is vague, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to title it better.

Essentially what I have is a module full of around 90 or so different functions, all that are differently named, and for the most part have (slightly) different code. I import a lot of data from excel sheets and need a function to match each one.

I currently rename each excel sheet and then use that string in `getattr` to call the correct function when reading in the excel file (my script loops through a folder and checks each file).

Short of using way too many `try except` statements, is there a way to do this where I DON'T have to rename the file and don't have to `try/except`?

I've thought about just searching through the excel sheet for the header and then searching for the column names I need in that header, but that seems very inefficient, as well as there are a large variety of different names for the same column type (ie, volume can be quantity, qty, vol, volume, nominal, etc).

I'm not really expecting there to be a much better way to do this, but here's hoping.

So this is what one of the functions I'm calling looks like:

```
 def test(path):
     df = pd.read_excel(path, sheetname=1, header=19, parse_cols='A, B, D, G, H')
     df = df.rename(columns={'ItemList': 'item', 'Volume': 'vol', 'Price': 'price', 'Date': 'date', 'Commish': 'com'})
     df = df.dropna()
     return df
```

I run my script, and it reads through a folder, `for filename in os.listdir(fpath)`

I strip the file type from `filename` (so `test.xlsx` becomes `test`) and then pass that into a function,

```
 def dfReturn(path, excelName):
     func = getattr(function_module, excelName)
     if func:
         df = func(path)
     return df
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of getattr, or at least make it so the file doesn't have to be named anything specific.

Comment: It's quite hard to answer this without seeing the code. Why do you have try/except blocks in the first place? If you don't need them, take them out. Why do you rename the file? If each of your functions operates on a specific filename, rewrite them so they take a `filename` parameter instead.

Comment: I don't, it's just something I was considering.

Comment: Assuming you're calling a script and pass it the excel file to process as an argument, you could as well pass the appropriate function as argument too...

Comment: I'll add some code and an example of the functions I'm calling. I'm trying to automate it more.

Comment: @Kevin I initially planned on just taking the generic file name in and matching that up. The problem is, the names of the excel files change all the time.

Comment: If I understood right, you have a different function to process each different file, is it?

Comment: @heltonbiker I have a separate function for each file. So, when I use getattr, it matches the name of the file with the correct function in the module. So, say, the `filename` is `test.xlsx`. `test` gets passed into `getattr`, and finds the `test` function. Then, it uses that function to parse the excel file.

Comment: Well, if that is already working I don't see a problem. Actually it is a clever way to solve your situation, although I can already foresee more experienced python users suggesting you to use a dictionary of some sort.

Comment: @Heltonbiker ha, I've already had some guys tell me that. I do it that way because it keeps things organized for me. I was hoping to be able to automate it a little more, but if not, well...it happens.

Comment: I think you have automated enough CONSIDERING two things what I find very uncomfortable: "file names keep changing" and "for the most part have (slightly) different [characteristics]". You seem to be living with spurious complexity, instead of fighting it - for exemple, having a common structure for every file. But each situation deserves its own treatment, and sometimes a pragmatic approach that works is much better than paralysis analysis led by a purist desire.

Comment: _I currently rename each excel sheet_ - how do you know how to rename them? Is that done in code? I take it the goal is to normalize column names in spreadsheets coming from... where? People who need a standard format, likely! You could, for instance, have a dict of common mappings `normalize_cols = {'itemlist':'item', ...}` and just change the column names you find in a given sheet.

Comment: @heltonbiker yeah, I would much rather they came standardized, but they're received from other businesses, instead of coming from within the office. Otherwise I'd tell someone to stop messing around with the excel sheets.

Comment: @tdelaney I rename all the excel sheets by hand, I built a list of who the sheets come from and what they need to be renamed to. It's not done in the code. Would using a dictionary like that speed anything up, though? I'd still be searching through rows/columns for the proper mapping, wouldn't I?